# PHP implementation into HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm currently beginning with PHP and I wanted to get started with a mini-project for some hands-on experience. Here's the code that I began with:

```html
<html>
<header>
 <title>Test</title>
</header>
<body>
 <h3>Some example title</h3>
 <?php
 $randomNumber = rand(1000,9000);
 print "Here's a random number: {$randomNumber}.";
 ?>
    <p>Some more text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I saved it as index.php and previewed it on Google Chrome, the PHP part doesn't show up. Can anyone help me realize what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you preview this code on a Webserver or just on you local computer?

Comment: Its working fine in my localhost. Check the file extension again. Also as Marat pointed out PHP is a server side language so it needs a sever to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run PHP code (**server side**) you need a server, or a 'server-emulator' some of the most commonly used are:

- [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html)
- [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Unlike the html in your `.php` files, the php code must be processed by a server and returned to the browser. I've tested your code with a server and it works like a charm.

---

After installing one of the above "emulators" you need to (this is a simplified tutorial, check a [real tutorial](https://blog.udemy.com/xampp-tutorial/)):

1. place your .php files in the public_html or htdocs folders that are
   created in the emulator's folder in your computer.
2. Turn on your server
3. go to localhost/your-file-path/index.php

---

If you only need to **test soft** code (like what's on yout example) and not develop whole projects use [IDONE](http://ideone.com/)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is used in the server side, so, you need to install an environment (Apache, PHP) to interpret the PHP. If you use Mac or Windows, you can install [Mamp](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/). For unix, you need to install some packages, i'll invite you to see this tutorial: [Lamp tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lamp-overview.html).